# Search random google query every 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to search a random google query every 30 minutes (e.g. https://www.google.com/?q=OjRfujaM). I need to search this without opening it in a new tab.

Please explain how I can do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Query the api https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: You'll have to explain the context a bit more to understand what you're trying to do.  Where are you displaying the results?  What are you trying to do with the search results?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not going to do anything with the search results, I just need to open the page and that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a block of code that will select randomly from a set of search phrases, open a new window and then put a google search for that phrase in that window and then, upon a time interval will change that window to a new google search. You didn't say how you wanted to select the random search phrase so I made up a way to do that, but you can obviously insert your own method.  Here's the code with [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pgkY5/):

```
var searchWindow, interval;
var searchPhrases = [
    "california earthquake", "desean jackson", "noah", 
    "louisville basketball", "ultra music festival", "january jones",
    "stephen colbert", "taco bell breakfast", "college board",
    "zac efron", "johnny manziel", "miguel cabrera", "psych"
];
function getRandomSearchPhrase() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * searchPhrases.length);
    return searchPhrases[rand];
}

function makeRandomGoogleSearchURL() {
    var search = encodeURI(getRandomSearchPhrase().replace(/\s/g, "+"));
    var url = "https://www.google.com?q=" + search + "#q=" + search;
    return url;
}

// create the interval portion to refresh the Google search
// use short time here for purposes of the demo
function startInterval() {
    if (interval) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (searchWindow && searchWindow.location) {
            // stop the interval if the window has been closed
            searchWindow.location = makeRandomGoogleSearchURL();
        } else {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            searchWindow = null;
        }
    }, 5000);
}

// hook up the button to start it all
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!searchWindow || !searchWindow.location) {
        searchWindow = window.open(makeRandomGoogleSearchURL(), "myGoogleSearch");
        startInterval();
    }
})
```

See working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pgkY5/

Comment: Would it be possible to close the window after being open for a couple of seconds?

Comment: You can call `searchWindow.close()` at some point, but I'm befuddled as to what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create a chrome extension like this one: http://pastebin.com/uX68yNAF (it was taken off the store)